# Javascript function gets incorrect boolean value from controller

Tags: apex, javascript

When my javascript function recieves a value from a controller boolean, it gets "false" instead of "true". Meanwhile, a System.log debug states that the boolean is "true". What could be causing this? There is much more code inside of the apex controller than I show below, so I'm thinking that possibly the javascript runs before the apex function is finished.

Here is the gist of the code:

VisualPage and Javascript

```
 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myAction}" reRender="something" oncomplete="myFunction();" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction(){
   window.alert({!myBoolean});
 }
 </script>
```

Apex Controller

```
public void myAction(){
  myBoolean = true;
  System.debug(myBoolean);
}
```

Comment: is the script in the `something` rerendered portion of the page?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, but in summary "something" does not rely on the "myFunction" . ReRendering is working though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the page loads, the `{!myBoolean}` expression gets the value of myBoolean at the time of the page load. So essentially the javascript function in your page would be:

```
function myFunction(){
   window.alert(false);
}
```

If the value of myBoolean is changed in the controller, you would also have to rerender the javascript function, or else it would remain as `alert(false);`

Moving the javascript function inside the `something` block should solve your problem.

Comment: You were correct, it was the placement of the script + reRendering the script. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please elaborate on the fix. I am saving boolean correctly in custom settings. But when vf Loads it is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

We should not bind Apex objects/variables directly in JavaScript (like you have `{!myBoolean}`). Previously had lots of issues with this and finally refactored the code to eliminate it. Instead use [JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) or the [Ajax Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm).

Not sure of the reason, but the value of the apex variable is what it is set in constructor or in getter for the first time. So javascript not getting the latest value after the execution of apex method.

Another workaround is using an `<apex:inputHidden>`, assign the variable to it and get its value using getElementById

```
<apex:inputhidden id="myBoolean" value="{!myBoolean}" />

var mybool = document.getElementById('myBoolean').value;
```

Hope it helps.